# How to count number of XY points within a polygon in Google Earth Engine

Tags: google-earth-engine

I am trying to count lat, long point values that fall within a polygon in Google Earth Engine. My dataset ("wells") has been uploaded as a table from a CSV. I am trying to count the number of wells in the polygon ("coastalplain").

For context, I am trying to perform density analysis on oil and gas wells on the Louisiana coastal plain, looking at how they vary by region.

This is my code.

````
Map.centerObject(wells);
Map.addLayer(wells, {color: 'red'}, 'Wells');
Map.addLayer(counties,{
   'color': 'black'
}, 'Counties', false);

var parishes = ee.FeatureCollection(
   'projects/landloss-2324/assets/louisianaparishes');
   
   print(parishes.size());
Map.addLayer(parishes,{
   'color': 'blue'
}, 'parishes');
   
var welltest = parishes.filterBounds(coastalplain);

var filtering = counties.filterBounds(welltest);
Map.addLayer(filtering,{}, 'WellsFilter');```
````

Comment: If possible, please provide a list of all assets you mentioned. This will help us better assist you.